# Entering information into HTML table

Tags: html, input, html-table, textbox, tablecell

I have an html table with some cells that need to be able to get user's input.
However, when I click on the cell nothing happens. Table is a part of a pop-up screen which is not a form (not sure if it should be) it's also nested in the fieldset.

```
<div class="div_popup" id="item_card">
  <fieldset id="item_card_quote_info" style="height: 25%; width: 95%; padding: 0%; margin:1%; ">
  <legend class="dash_text" style="margin-left: 1%; margin-right:3%; margin-bottom: 0.5%; padding-top: 0%"> Quote Information </legend>
    <table id = "ic_quote_pricing" style=" background-color:grey; 
                 width:100%; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial'; ">
      <col width="10%">
      <col width="10%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >Cost</th>
          <th >Qty</th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input id="ic_q_unit_cost" style="display: table-cell; width:100%" type="text" >
          </td>
          <td>
              <input id="ic_q_unit_qty" style="display: table-cell; width: 100%" type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i was trying different types. textbox works in other places in my program but that could be legacy code. Anyway, after i changed type to text it still doesn't work

Comment: It's working fine with the your code. Isn't it??  Here it is in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-zrqmn?fontsize=14)

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi That's strange. It works in your link, but doesn't in my code. I will have to double check everything

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi. My table is nested in the fieldset. Will that make any difference? I don't think it should.

Comment: It shouldn't! try posting relevant code if problem still persists.

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi. I added complete code. Table is part of the pop up screen that have a fieldset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a issue with your Popup CSS. I have found some Custom CSS for popup and implemented with the same available code. It's working and should be fine with you too.

**some.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Popup</h1>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Click me!</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <fieldset id="item_card_quote_info" style="height: 25%; width: 95%; padding: 0%; margin:1%; ">
        <legend class="dash_text" style="margin-left: 1%; margin-right:3%; margin-bottom: 0.5%; padding-top: 0%"> Quote Information </legend>
          <table id = "ic_quote_pricing" style=" background-color:grey; 
                       width:100%; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial'; ">
            <col width="10%">
            <col width="10%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th >Cost</th>
                <th >Qty</th>
              </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input id="ic_q_unit_cost" style="display: table-cell; width:100%" type="text" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="ic_q_unit_qty" style="display: table-cell; width: 100%" type="text">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a possibility. I am checking it out thanks.

Comment: My issue is that while making pop-up draggable it disables the elements for input.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that while making my pop-up draggable i was disabling default onmousedown events for input boxes.